Migrating Docker Compose Microservices to .NET Aspire
Problem Description
I'm attempting to migrate a existing microservices architecture from Docker Compose to .NET Aspire, and I'm encountering some complex configuration challenges.
Current Setup
I have a microservices solution with the following services:

Gateway Service: Ocelot Gateway
Marketplace Service: ASP.NET CORE
Users Service: ASP.NET CORE
Stock Service: SpringBoot

The existing Docker Compose file uses multiple databases (SQL Server, PostgreSQL), Redis, and RabbitMQ, with specific port mappings and environment configurations.
Migration Attempt
I've created an initial Aspire project structure
services:
  #############################################################
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: [ "redis-server", "--save", "60", "1", "--loglevel", "warning" ]
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  #############################################################
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672" # Port for RabbitMQ (AMQP protocol)
      - "15672:15672" # Port for RabbitMQ Management UI
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    networks:
      - app-network
  #############################################################
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: sqlserver
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Coding@1234?"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
      - sqlserver_data:/var/opt/mssql
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - app-network
  #############################################################
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: stock
      POSTGRES_USER: stockuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: stockpassword
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - app-network
  #############################################################
  gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gateway
    container_name: gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/infrastructure/Gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_PASS=guest
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
  #############################################################
  marketplaceservice.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}marketplaceserviceapi
    container_name: marketplaceservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/services/MarketplaceService/src/MarketplaceService.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_PASS=guest
      - DB_HOST=sqlserver
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
  #############################################################
  usersservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}usersservice
    container_name: usersservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/services/UsersService/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5002:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_PASS=guest
      - DB_HOST=sqlserver
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
  #############################################################
  stockservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}stockservice
    container_name: stockservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/services/stockservice/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgresql
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
#############################################################
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    name: microservices_postgres_data
  sqlserver_data:
    name: microservices_sqlserver_data
  redis_data:
    name: microservices_redis_data



...what's your question?  There are a couple of things you could simplify in the Compose setup, but at first glance it seems fine.
